# Does JavaFX 2.0 run on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, javafx, javafx-2

As I just read about the release of JavaFX 2.0 beta and the NetBeans 7.0 plugin in the article [JavaFX: The Resurrection (Java FX 2.0 Released)](http://java.dzone.com/dose/daily-dose-javafx-resurrection), is there information available if it runs on Google App Engine for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client technologies that require GUI (Swing, JavaFX or even JS+HTML/DOM) don't run on servers, because, well, servers don't have screens to display GUI.

JavaFX is a client technology: e.g. it runs as a desktop app or as an applet inside your browser.

Server support is limited to talking to servers via some kind of RPC and, in case of applet, being hosted on a server for users to download. GAE can do both (depends on type of RPC).

Comment: I think there may be a way to run JavaFX because if we can use Flex in GAE why not JavaFX

Comment: Flex does not run on GAE. However, SWF files created by Flex can be hosted on GAE and then downloaded by users into browser where they are executed by Flash plugin, i.e. they "run" in browser. GAE can host (= make available to download) many different files, including swf, java applets, html+javascript. But this does not mean that they run on GAE.

Answer (score 3):

GAE deals with the server and according to its spec it only supports Python, Java, Go as a **server side** technology.

Technologies like JavaFX, Flex, JavaScript etc. are **client side** technologies. It does not matter what you use in client side its gonna work anyway. As long as GAE is there you have to deal with only Python, Java and Go in order to run on App Engine.